Не могу поменять местами компоненты торговых предложений в 1с битрикс
Я вывела торговые предложения, мне необходимо визуально поменять местами основное окно, как это вообще делается. ИМЕННО В ВИЗУАЛЬНОМ, а не в таблице?

